# iOSアプリで画面遷移に伴うFirebaseのバグ

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, firebase, uitableview

## やりたいこと

*FirstView*から*TableView*へ画面遷移した時に，1月の値がインクリメントされ，値が多い順に上から*Cell*に表示する．

## これまでの流れ

1. 新しいプロジェクトを作成する．
2. *Firebase*とアプリを接続する．
3. **写真1**のようにオブジェクトを配置する．
4. **コード1**と**コード2**を記述する．
5. **写真3**のように*Realtime Database*を構成する．
6. プロジェクトを実行すると**写真4**のようになる．

## 問題点

1月が*Cell*に表示されない．
（インクリメントする月を変えても，そのインクリメントした月が表示されない．）
（*print()*で*Log*を監視しても表示がない．）

## コード1

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ref = Database.database().reference().child("This")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.ref.child("1月").runTransactionBlock { (MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            if let inc = MutableData.value as? Int {
                MutableData.value = inc + 1
            }
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: MutableData)
        }
    }
}
```

## コード2

*TableViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var list: UITableView!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var rank = [(key: String, value: Int)]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ref = Database.database().reference().child("This")
        self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
            let namesArray = DataSnapshot.value as! [String: Int]
            self.rank = namesArray.sorted {$0.value > $1.value}
            self.list.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.rank.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.rank[indexPath.row].key
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(self.rank[indexPath.row].value)
        return cell
    }
}
```

## 写真1

*Main.storyboard*
[image]

## 写真2

構成
[image]

## 写真3

*Firebase*
[image]

## 写真4

デバイス上
[image]

## 環境

xcode : ver11.0
Swift : ver5.1
iOS : ver13.1.2

## 最後に

お力をお貸しください．宜しくお願い致します．
（分かり難所があれば言ってください）

Comment: Firebaseは自分では使っていないので、今回の件を確実に解決できるか自信はないのですが、データ更新処理が`ViewController.viewWillDisappear(_:)`で起動されているので、遷移先の`TableViewController.viewDidLoad()`が動いた時にはまだ完了していない(場合によっては起動さえしていない可能性もありますが)可能性が高そうです。データ更新の開始を別のところ(`TableViewController.viewDidLoad()`より確実に先に呼ばれるところ)で処理を行い、完了するまでは画面遷移を行わない、と言った変更を行うのが一つの手でしょう。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/215571

Comment: 知識不足ですいません．ある処理が終わるまで画面遷移を行わないようにする方法はあるのですか？